# Optimizing Perlin noise in Haskell

Tags: haskell, optimization, perlin-noise

(Dependencies for this program: `vector --any` and `JuicyPixels >= 2`. Code is available as [Gist](https://gist.github.com/rhymoid/5221478).)

```
{-# LANGUAGE Haskell2010 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Control.Arrow
import Data.Bits
import Data.Vector.Unboxed ((!))
import Data.Word
import System.Environment (getArgs)

import qualified Codec.Picture as P
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
```

I tried to port [Ken Perlin's improved noise](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/)
to Haskell, but I'm not entirely sure that my method is correct. The main part
is something that should generalize nicely to higher and lower dimensions, but
that is something for later:

```
perlin3 :: (Ord a, Num a, RealFrac a, V.Unbox a) => Permutation -> (a, a, a) -> a
perlin3 p (!x', !y', !z')
  = let (!xX, !x) = actuallyProperFraction x'
        (!yY, !y) = actuallyProperFraction y'
        (!zZ, !z) = actuallyProperFraction z'

        !u = fade x
        !v = fade y
        !w = fade z

        !h = xX
        !a = next p h + yY
        !b = next p (h+1) + yY
        !aa = next p a + zZ
        !ab = next p (a+1) + zZ
        !ba = next p b + zZ
        !bb = next p (b+1) + zZ
        !aaa = next p aa
        !aab = next p (aa+1)
        !aba = next p ab
        !abb = next p (ab+1)
        !baa = next p ba
        !bab = next p (ba+1)
        !bba = next p bb
        !bbb = next p (bb+1)

    in
        lerp w
            (lerp v
                (lerp u
                    (grad aaa (x, y, z))
                    (grad baa (x-1, y, z)))
                (lerp u
                    (grad aba (x, y-1, z))
                    (grad bba (x-1, y-1, z))))
            (lerp v
                (lerp u
                    (grad aab (x, y, z-1))
                    (grad bab (x-1, y, z-1)))
                (lerp u
                    (grad abb (x, y-1, z-1))
                    (grad bbb (x-1, y-1, z-1))))
```

This is of course accompanied by a few functions mentioned in the `perlin3`
function, of which I hope they are as efficient as possible:

```
fade :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a
fade !t | 0 <= t, t <= 1 = t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10)

lerp :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> a -> a
lerp !t !a !b | 0 <= t, t <= 1 = a + t * (b - a)

grad :: (Bits hash, Integral hash, Num a, V.Unbox a) => hash -> (a, a, a) -> a
grad !hash (!x, !y, !z) = dot3 (vks `V.unsafeIndex` fromIntegral (hash .&. 15)) (x, y, z)
  where
    vks = V.fromList
        [ (1,1,0), (-1,1,0), (1,-1,0), (-1,-1,0)
        , (1,0,1), (-1,0,1), (1,0,-1), (-1,0,-1)
        , (0,1,1), (0,-1,1), (0,1,-1), (0,-1,-1)
        , (1,1,0), (-1,1,0), (0,-1,1), (0,-1,-1)
        ]

dot3 :: Num a => (a, a, a) -> (a, a, a) -> a
dot3 (!x0, !y0, !z0) (!x1, !y1, !z1) = x0 * x1 + y0 * y1 + z0 * z1

-- Unlike `properFraction`, `actuallyProperFraction` rounds as intended.
actuallyProperFraction :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> (b, a)
actuallyProperFraction x
  = let (ipart, fpart) = properFraction x
        r = if x >= 0 then (ipart, fpart)
                      else (ipart-1, 1+fpart)
    in r
```

For the permutation group, I just copied the one Perlin used on his website:

```
newtype Permutation = Permutation (V.Vector Word8)

mkPermutation :: [Word8] -> Permutation
mkPermutation xs
    | length xs >= 256
    = Permutation . V.fromList $ xs

permutation :: Permutation
permutation = mkPermutation
    [151,160,137,91,90,15,
   131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,
   190, 6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,
   88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168, 68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,
   77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,
   102,143,54, 65,25,63,161, 1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208, 89,18,169,200,196,
   135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186, 3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,
   5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,
   223,183,170,213,119,248,152, 2,44,154,163, 70,221,153,101,155,167, 43,172,9,
   129,22,39,253, 19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185, 112,104,218,246,97,228,
   251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241, 81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,
   49,192,214, 31,181,199,106,157,184, 84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127, 4,150,254,
   138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180
   ]

next :: Permutation -> Word8 -> Word8
next (Permutation !v) !idx'
  = v `V.unsafeIndex` (fromIntegral $ idx' .&. 0xFF)
```

And all this is tied together with JuicyPixels:

```
main = do
    [target] <- getArgs
    let image = P.generateImage pixelRenderer 512 512
    P.writePng target image
  where
    pixelRenderer, pixelRenderer' :: Int -> Int -> Word8
    pixelRenderer !x !y
        = floor $ ((perlin3 permutation ((fromIntegral x - 256) / 32,
          (fromIntegral y - 256) / 32, 0 :: Double))+1)/2 * 128

    -- This code is much more readable, but also much slower.
    pixelRenderer' x y
        = (\w -> floor $ ((w+1)/2 * 128)) -- w should be in [-1,+1]
        . perlin3 permutation
        . (\(x,y,z) -> ((x-256)/32, (y-256)/32, (z-256)/32))
        $ (fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, 0 :: Double)
```

My problem is that `perlin3` seems very slow to me. If I profile it, `pixelRenderer`
is getting a lot of time as well, but I'll ignore that for now. I don't know
how to optimize `perlin3`. I tried to hint GHC with bang patterns, which cuts
the execution time in half, so that's nice. Explicitly specializing and inlining
barely helps with `ghc -O`. Is `perlin3` supposed to be this slow?

---

**UPDATE**: an earlier version of this question mentioned a bug in my code. This problem has been resolved; it turns out my old version of `actuallyProperFraction` was buggy. It implicitly rounded the integral part of a floating point number to `Word8`, and then subtracted it from the floating point number to get the fractional part. Since `Word8` can only take values between `0` and `255` inclusive, this won't work properly for numbers outside that range, including negative numbers.

Comment: How are you profiling it?  Profiling with `-auto-all` disables some optimizations to profile more accurately.  I get a factor of 2.5 slowdown using `-auto-all`, relative to `-auto`.

Comment: I had `ghc -O -o /tmp/IPerlin -prof -rtsopts -auto-all -caf-all -fforce-recomp IPerlin.lhs`, then calling it as `/tmp/IPerlin +RTS -p -RTS /tmp/output.png`. `-auto` is indeed much faster, but now the profiling report contains barely any information (no mention of `perlin3`). Also, I hardly know what I should be looking for :P

Comment: I think that `grad` could be improved by using a different type for `vks`.  The `Unbox` instance for tuples actually stores them as a tuple of arrays.  If you create a triple type and an unbox instance that stores the values consecutively it should be an improvement.  Making your triple strict would also simplify some of the other code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code appears to be mostly computation-bound.  It can be improved a little bit, but not by much unless there's a way to use fewer array lookups and less arithmetic.

There are two useful tools for measuring performance: profiling and code dumps.  I added an SCC annotation to `perlin3` so that it would show up in the profile.  Then I compiled with `gcc -O2 -fforce-recomp -ddump-simpl -prof -auto`.  The `-ddump-simpl` flag prints the simplified code.

*Profiling:* On my computer, it takes 0.60 seconds to run the program, and about 20% of execution time (0.12 seconds) is spent in `perlin3` according to the profile.  Note that the precision of my profile info is about +/-3%.

*Simplifier output:* The simplifier produces fairly clean code.  `perlin3` gets inlined into `pixelRenderer`, so that's the part of the output you want to look at.  Most of the code consists of unboxed array reads and unboxed arithmetic.  To improve performance, we want to eliminate some of this arithmetic.

An easy change is to eliminate the run-time checks on `SomeFraction` (which doesn't appear in your question, but is part of the code that you uploaded).  This reduces the program's execution time to 0.56 seconds.

```
-- someFraction t | 0 <= t, t < 1 = SomeFraction t
someFraction t = SomeFraction t
```

Next, there are several array lookups that show up in the simplifier like this:

```
                 case GHC.Prim.indexWord8Array#
                        ipv3_s23a
                        (GHC.Prim.+#
                           ipv1_s21N
                           (GHC.Prim.word2Int#
                              (GHC.Prim.and#
                                 (GHC.Prim.narrow8Word#
                                    (GHC.Prim.plusWord# ipv5_s256 (__word 1)))
                                 (__word 255))))
```

The primitive operation `narrow8Word#` is for coercing from an `Int` to a `Word8`.  We can get rid of this coercion by using `Int` instead of `Word8` in the definition of `next`.

```
next :: Permutation -> Int -> Int
next (Permutation !v) !idx'
  = fromIntegral $ v `V.unsafeIndex` (fromIntegral idx' .&. 0xFF)
```

This reduces the program's execution time to 0.54 seconds.  Considering just the time spent in `perlin3`, the execution time has fallen (roughly) from 0.12 to 0.06 seconds.  Although it's hard to measure where the rest of the time is going, it's most likely spread out among the remaining arithmetic and array accesses.

Comment: So I guess I should focus on optimizing `grad`/`dot3` and the permutation function, if anything. Thanks for taking the time to look at it :) To note, the `someFraction` runtime-check was just to see whether my assumptions about certain values were (probably) correct, so that check should indeed be removed in production code. I'll look further into it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

On my machine reference code with Heatsink's optimisations takes 0.19 secs.

Firstly, I has moved from `JuicyPixels` to `yarr` and `yarr-image-io` with my favourite flags, `-Odph -rtsopts -threaded -fno-liberate-case -funbox-strict-fields -fexpose-all-unfoldings -funfolding-keeness-factor1000 -fsimpl-tick-factor=500 -fllvm -optlo-O3` (they are given [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yarr/1.3.1/doc/html/Data-Yarr.html)):

```
import Data.Yarr as Y
import Data.Yarr.IO.Image as Y
...

main = do
    [target] <- getArgs
    image <- dComputeS $ fromFunction (512, 512) (return . pixelRenderer)
    Y.writeImage target (Grey image)
  where
    pixelRenderer, pixelRenderer' :: Dim2 -> Word8
    pixelRenderer (y, x)
        = floor $ ((perlin3 permutation ((fromIntegral x - 256) / 32,
          (fromIntegral y - 256) / 32, 0 :: Double))+1)/2 * 128

    -- This code is much more readable, but also much slower.
    pixelRenderer' (y, x)
        = (\w -> floor $ ((w+1)/2 * 128)) -- w should be in [-1,+1]
        . perlin3 permutation
        . (\(x,y,z) -> ((x-256)/32, (y-256)/32, (z-256)/32))
        $ (fromIntegral x, fromIntegral y, 0 :: Double)
```

This makes the program 30% faster, 0.13 seconds.

Secondly I has replaced uses of standard `floor` with

```
doubleToByte :: Double -> Word8
doubleToByte f = fromIntegral (truncate f :: Int)
```

It is known issue (google "haskell floor performance"). Execution time is reduced to 52 ms (0.052 secs), in almost 3 times.

Finally, just for fun I tried to compute noise in parallel (`dComputeP` instead of `dComputeS` and `+RTS -N4` in command line run). Program took 36 ms, including I/O constant of about 10 ms.

Comment: Although this doesn't optimize the Perlin noise function itself, it cuts down the total execution time a lot. Replacing `floor` by itself is already a huge performance boost (from 5.42 s to 2.40 s, for a 4 Mipx image). I'm not sure if I want to move to `yarr-image-io` (I don't know how much harder packaging for Windows becomes if I start using DevIL), but I'll certainly look into `yarr`. Thanks for the hint, and for showing off your library! :)

Comment: @Rhymoid consider also replacing x-y-z boilerplate with control flow from `fixed-vector` library. Ex., `dot3 = sum . zipWith (*)` ([sum](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fixed-vector/0.1.2.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Fixed.html#v:sum), [zipWith](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fixed-vector/0.1.2.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Fixed.html#v:zipWith))